# Selecting a record based off conditions CLOB

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have a table with a column storing JSON data as a CLOB. The JSON has a 'miscData' field that is made up of an array of JSON objects. Each object has 2 keys which are always the same, but the values are different.

```
.
.
.
"otherKeys" : "otherValues",
"miscData": [
        {
            "miscType": "date",
            "miscText": "2020-07-09T10:01:10.450Z"
        },
        {
            "miscType": "Comment",
            "miscText": "Comment body"
        },
        {
            "miscType": "CORRECT_TYPE",
            "miscText": "SELECT_ME"
        }
    ],
"confirmationNumber" : "123456789qwerty",
.
.
.
```

I need to

```
SELECT 
    CLOB_COL.miscData.miscText 
WHERE
    CLOB_COL.miscData.miscType = 'CORRECT_TYPE' 
AND 
    CLOB_COL.confirmationNumber = 'xxxx';
```

But I am having trouble since miscData is an array of objects which all contain miscType and miscData keys and I can't guarantee the array will be the same size, or in the same order.

Comment: Why not use `JSONTable()`?

Comment: @MichaelKutz perfectly valid question! I am very new to Oracle and more complex SQL in general, so more or less I wasn't having any luck finding the right operator/functions. I will look into JSONTable(), looks promising so far! I will check back with my results. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

After surviving the ordeal of installing Oracle 12c on Devuan, I came up with this query using json_exists:

```
select
  t.id,
  t.data.miscData,
  t.data.miscData.miscType,
  t.data.confirmationNumber
  from json_documents t
  where json_exists(
          t.data,
          '$.miscData?(@.miscType=="CORRECT_TYPE")'
        )
    and json_exists(
          t.data,
          '$?(@.confirmationNumber=="123456789qwerty")'
        )
```

FYI:

```
CREATE TABLE json_documents (
  id    RAW(16) NOT NULL,
  data  CLOB,
  CONSTRAINT json_documents_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT json_documents_json CHECK (data IS JSON (STRICT))
)
```